# Why doesn't apache load my .so libraries when I try to run my flask application?

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi, shared-libraries

I have a developed flask application which runs successfully on flask's embedded server.  The application uses a backend written in C++.  The libraries for my C++ backend are in this folder:

> /home/(USER_NAME)/rf/Dev/Backend/lib/libtestCAF.so

When I run the application on the embedded server, it finds the C++ backend code and uses it to generate reports.  However, when I run the same application on apache, I get this error trace:

```
[Thu Jul 11 14:44:54 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     from main.main import main
[Thu Jul 11 14:44:54 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/(USER_NAME)/rf/Dev/Web/main/main.py", line 19, in <module>
[Thu Jul 11 14:44:54 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     from CAF.CAFWrapper import *
[Thu Jul 11 14:44:54 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/admin1/rf/Dev/Web/CAF/CAFWrapper.py", line 12, in <module>
[Thu Jul 11 14:44:54 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('../Backend/lib/libtestCAF.so')
[Thu Jul 11 14:44:54 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 443, in LoadLibrary
[Thu Jul 11 14:44:54 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     return self._dlltype(name)
[Thu Jul 11 14:44:54 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
[Thu Jul 11 14:44:54 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
[Thu Jul 11 14:44:54 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] OSError: ../Backend/lib/libtestCAF.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

As you can see on that last line, it says that libtestCAF.so doesn't exist.  Meanwhile, the embedded server always finds it.

I use mod_wsgi to run the flask application on the apache server.  The WSGI file I use is in this folder:

```
/home/(USER_NAME)/rf/Dev/Web/wsgi/rf.wsgi
```

... and it says this:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'home/(USER_NAME)/rf/Dev/Web')
from runserver import app as application
```

This is my apache config file:

```
<VirtualHost *:8100>
    ServerName www.relativefinder.com

    WSGIDaemonProcess rf user=www-data group=www-data threads=5
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/(USER_NAME)/rf/Dev/Web/wsgi/rf.wsgi

    <Directory /home/(USER_NAME)/rf/Dev>
        WSGIProcessGroup rf
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The python file which loads the .so files uses the following code:

```
if SettingsToUse == DEV_CAF:
    lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('../Backend/lib/librelativefinder.so')
else:
    lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('../Backend/lib/libtestCAF.so')
```

I'm quite confused that Apache doesn't seem to find it but the embedded server in flask always appears to find it.  What do I need to do so that, when I run apache, it will find that .so file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using a relative path name and not an absolute path name. The current working directory when running under Apache will not be the where your source code is. See:

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues#Application_Working_Directory

Comment: Thanks for the link.  When I get into work tomorrow, I'll be sure to change it to an absolute path name, just to check if it works.  However, I do worry about the prospect of using an absolute path name since it is notoriously inflexible.  Is there any way of doing this without using absolute paths?

Comment: Thanks man!  You guys are a big help.